# Can we combine a image texture and a ies light on a spot lamp?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, geometry

I wanto make the gobo light effect so i want to combine the stencil and the effect of ies file , with shader enable on spot , trying to make in cycle engine , can anyone help me to build one

Comment: Can you make a 'physical' gobo out of geometry? (It wouldn't have to be visible to the camera)